# Formula to calculate salary after x year?

Tags: excel

Knowing that i am getting paid $10 000 a year, and that each year my salary increase by 5%.
What is the formula for Excel to know how much i will get in 5 year?
Thank you for any advise

Comment: so you're at 23,000 a year now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula in Excel is:

```
=VF(5%;5;0;-10000)
```

Which results in: $12,762.82

If your Office is english version you can use:

```
=FV(5%;5;0;-10000)
```

Comment: I think it is best to go for the Excel built in functions for transparancy and speed so this gets my vote

Answer (score 6):

```
=(10000*((1 + 0.05)^5))
```

The Compound Interest Equation
P = C (1 + r/n)^nt 
 
Where...
    P = Future Value
    C = Initial Deposit/Salary
    r = Interest Rate/Pay Increase (Expressed as a Fraction: EX = 0.05)
    n = Number of Times per Year the Interest/Pay Raise Is Compounded (0 in Your Example)
    t = Number of Years to Calculate

Answer (score 1):

The Formula is POWER(B1,C1)*10000, and the cell B1 is (1+5% ), the cell C1 is the number of years

Answer (score 0):

```
current = 10 000
for each year -1
 current = current * 1.05
end for
```

current now has current salary for the given number of years